# @OrderColumn in JPQL query

Tags: jpa, join, many-to-many, jpql

I am having a @ManyToMany mapping with @OrderColumn as follows:

```
class Tag {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) @Getter
    @JoinTable(
            name = "tag_graph",
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"))
    private Set<Tag> parents = new TreeSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parents") @Getter @OrderColumn
    private List<Tag> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

My problem is that I want to write an JPQL query which would use the @OrderColumn of the generated @JoinTable. Something like:

```
 SELECT t FROM Tag t WHERE ... ORDER BY t.ORDER_COLUMN
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use the INDEX function in JPQL.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#Special_Operators

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to specify the order column in queries, it's automatically used behind the scenes to preserve the order in which elements have been added to the relationship list. For a better explanation you can refer to this [link](http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/3898336/The-Top-5-New-Annotations-in-JPA-2.htm).

Comment: The @OrderColumn is automatically handled only on the entity, but not in the JPA query, which I need to use. I need to create specific JOIN/WHERE query, which would be eventually sorted by the ordercolumn.

Comment: In that case you need to manage such a column by yourself, since the `@OrderColumn` is opaque and there is no way to access it explicitly.